# How to find a private class A IP address assigned to cable modem by DHCP server?

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, private-network

How to find a private (Class A) cable RF IP address (10.x.x.x) assigned to cable modem by provisioning system in DOCSIS cable network node?
In certain situations, when device is online, the IP address at which the device can be accessed within the network, is private (class A) cable RF IP address 10.x.x.x, not default 192.168.x.x

Comment: Documentation or the back of the modem? I would hazard to guess however your issue is not that the modem is configured in the   10.0.0.0/8 block but that your ISP is configuring the modems LAN facing IP. So you'd have to ask them.

Comment: So this 10. address is on the outside of the cable modem, so your internal network is still 192.198.*? In this instance I don't think there's any way to determine it programmatically unless the cable modem provides some means such as an API.

Comment: 192.168.x.x is default address of web UI, but it is inaccessible when modem is online. A private class A IP addresses 10.x.x.x is assigned to devices within network node. These private IPs is accessible within node.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question then this should work.

You may need to modify for your environment but a kluge would be to get the second hop IP in a traceroute . Something like :

```
$ echo "Router IP: `traceroute 8.8.8.8 | awk '  /^ 2/ { print $2 ; exit  } '` " 
Router External IP: 10.0.9.1
```

Comment: @Joe M I tried run command, terminal hangs for a few minutes, then return public IP address 91.x.x.x

Comment: @minto - Ooh , ok try traceroute by itself without the awk and paste the output below and I can see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @Joe M traceroute to google-public-dns (8.8.8.8) take 10 hops, all IPs is public  range IPs. The 2nd public IP is same that show full command above.

Comment: Well, I find the method. The solution is use Wireshark to sniff communication and reboot device. Private IP address is shown during DHCP provisioning flow.